# How do I add buttons over an image using the netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, ide

I am using netbeans as an IDE to make my desktop application.

I have to add 3 buttons over an image. How do I do that? I have been unable to do this using the drag and drop features of netbeans.

Comment: Can you give us a screen shot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @MadProgrammer http://i40.tinypic.com/aaue6b.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Put the buttons in a custom panel with an image background ([example here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm)).

In IDE use a regular `JPanel` and drag the `JButton`s over it, then change the code from `JPanel` to `ImagePanel` (or whatever name you used for it).

Answer (score 0):

This is a little cheeky, but.

- Start by setting the layout of the base component to `BorderLayout`.
- Drop a `JLabel` into it. Set the labels icon image to the background image you want to use.
- Set the layout manager of the label to what ever you want to use.
- Drop your buttons onto it...

Answer (score 0):

1.Add the JLabel and in Properties, Set text to null and add the image by selecting it from the icons menu (this image should be in your package).

2.Set the appropriate size of the background and set the layout to NULL Layout.

3.Place the background label as the bottom most layer and keep adding buttons or labels as per your need.